# Recommendations for simple volunteer reminder application

Tags: javascript, html

I am associated with a non-profit that has asked me to help them create a basic application with the following requirements:

1. Must be able to run on mac and pc.
2. Purpose of the app is to manage a list of volunteers, and send emails to the volunteers reminding them of an upcoming shift.  They have it set up so that a person volunteers for the 1st Monday of every month, or the 3rd Thursday of every month, etc.  They want to be able to select a range of dates, and have the app find out which day of the month falls in those dates (2nd Monday, or 3rd Friday, etc) and email the volunteers a reminder.
3. They need to be able to edit the volunteer list for each of the days.
4. They need to have a basic report showing all the days of the month and the volunteers for that day.  Basic text is fine.

I was thinking that I could do this as a simple html + javascript app, with the data stored in an xml file.  The hangup I am having, is that in order to send the emails, it needs to call a server-side script.  I was hoping to have this be a completely self-contained app that doesn't require a server to run.  I can't do it as a windows app, because it needs to be able to run on a MAC.  So I thought a simple web page would work.

But the email sending, is the problem...

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: It's impossible to send mail without mail server, if you dont setup your own, you'll have to use other, maybe someone supports the mail sending through REST api. Maybe one option could be http://documentation.mailgun.net/user_manual.html

Comment: Node.js works on both platforms and can act as the server. You can use JavaScript for both the web app and the email handling.

Comment: @pimvdb I will definitely be checking out Node.js.  Thanks!

Comment: To use node is developp a server-side application , you'll need to call the node script via http anyway.

Comment: I was thinking of a web app, with Node just filling the gaps (e.g. sending emails). As a side note, by deploying Chromium along you don't have cross-browser issues either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send emails you'll need a mail server , wether it is a remote one or something on the client's local computer. I'd go with a web app hosted on a server , makes more sense.